# Error in build config in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, build.gradle

I am running a app in Android Studio. Following is the code:

### strings.xml

```
<resources>
  <string name="google_nearby_api_key">XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX</string>
</resources>
```

### Manifest file

```
<application
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.nearby.messages.API_KEY"
        android:value="@string/google_nearby_api_key"/>
</application>
```

### build.gradle

```
def filesAuthorityValue = applicationId + ".files"
manifestPlaceholders = [filesAuthority: filesAuthorityValue]
buildConfigField "String", "FILES_AUTORITY", "\"${filesAuthorityValue}\""
resValue "string", "google_nearby_api_key", getLocalProperties().getProperty("google_nearby_api_key")
```

I get the error:

```
Error:(35, 0) Build Config field cannot have a null parameter
```

Can anyone please help on this?

Comment: Try to click on synchronize, on the right side of save. Do that after gradle sync. OR In Android Studio: Build -> Clean Project

Comment: Sir, I clicked on Clean Project. It dint respond

Comment: `getLocalProperties()` is refering to which properties file?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I checked on my machine this is working for me

local.properties

```
GOOGLE_NEARBY_API_KEY="XXXXXXXXXX"
```

build.gradle

```
Properties properties = new Properties()
properties.load(project.rootProject.file('local.properties').newDataInputStream())
resValue "string", "google_nearby_api_key", properties.getProperty('GOOGLE_NEARBY_API_KEY')
```

You will find the generated file with your string in:

`app/build/generated/res/resValues/{build-type}/values/generated.xml`

Now you can use the string in your app as `@string/google_nearby_api_key`.

Also, when I removed the key from `local.properties` I am getting the same error:

```
Error:(17, 1) A problem occurred evaluating project ':app'.
> Build Config field cannot have a null parameter
```

So, you probably do not have the key in your `local.properties`.

And you also seemed to have manually added the string in your `strings.xml` resource file, you shouldn't do this if you want to hide your API key. Inject it through your `gradle` build (the above approach).